# Problem with with ES2020 dynamic import()

Tags: javascript, dynamic-import, ecmascript-2020

I'm parsing all the modules in a directory, initialise them, and finally export them. The modules in question are `knex` models like this one:

```
// schema/users.js

import createModel from './common'

const name = 'User'
const tableName = 'users'

const selectableProps = ['userId', 'name', 'email', 'updated_at', 'created_at']

export default knex => {
  const model = createModel({
    knex,
    name,
    tableName,
    selectableProps,
  })

  return { ...model }
}
```

Each of the model definitions is extended with common parts:

```
// schema/common.js
export default ({
  knex = {},
  name = 'name',
  tableName = 'tablename',
  selectableProps = [],
  timeout = 1000,
}) => {
  const findAll = () =>
    knex
      .select(selectableProps)
      .from(tableName)
      .timeout(timeout)

  return {
    name,
    tableName,
    selectableProps,
    timeout,
    findAll,
  }
}
```

Finally, all models are initialised and exported:

```
// schema/index.js
import { readdir } from 'fs'
import { promisify } from 'util'
import { default as knex } from '../db'

let modules = {}

export default new Promise(async $export => {
  const readFileAsync = promisify(readdir)

  const getModels = async dir => await readFileAsync(dir)

  const files = await getModels(__dirname)

  for await (const file of files) {
    if (file !== 'common.js' && file !== 'index.js') {
      let mod = await import(__dirname + '/' + file).then(m => m.default(knex))
      modules[mod.name] = mod
    }
  }

  await $export(modules)
  console.log(modules)
})
```

The above seem to be working but I'm not able to figure out how to import one of these modules from another file. I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
const User = async () => await import('../schema') // not working
```

or

```
const User = (async () => await import('../schema'))() // not working
```

Any help with this will be appreciated!

Comment: `not working` doesn't seem to be a feasible error message that tells you what is wrong. o0 Would be nice to know.

Comment: I actually reverted to using commonJS-style imports on the back end, and all is well :-)